# Way to know what was the last line executed before entering a catch block with Intellij?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

A recurring issue when debugging is that I'm going through line by line in the code and then I suddenly, out of nowhere, jump to a catch block. As I was going through so many lines I can't really remember which line caused the catch-block to be executed.

Does Intellij provide any kind of facility that allows me to easily check what was the last line executed in a given try-block?

PS: If I'm dealing with a pure function, things are not so terrible. I can just drop frame and go again through the code, paying particular care to see which one is the last line executed by the try-block before getting into the catch-block. But even that is tedious if the method is long enough..

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using exception breakpoints for this particular exception?

Comment: No. The issue is that I'm a lot of times caught off-guard, so only after the fact I get worried about knowing where I came from.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I had this requirement as well. There are two options you can try:

#### plain intellij without installing plugin

when you stop in a `catch` block, use `expression evaluation (alt-F8)` and execute `e (or ex whatever the Exception var named) .printStackTrace()`, then in your console you see the stacktrace, it pointed out which line caused the exception.

In this way, you can only know the line number from the stacktrace, however if you want to go there and check the problem, you have to drop frame/re-start the debug.

#### install chronon plugin in intellij

This plugin supports step forward/backwards, also method call history functions etc. And if an exception occurred, it can locate the line caused the exception as well. Then you can `alt-f6` to go back to the line, check what was going on.